# How to import csv data file into scikit-learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

From my understanding, the scikit-learn accepts data in (n-sample, n-feature) format which is a 2D array. Assuming I have data in the form ...

```
Stock prices    indicator1    indicator2
2.0             123           1252
1.0             ..            ..
..              .             . 
.
```

How do I import this?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

This is not a CSV file; this is just a space separated file. Assuming there are no missing values, you can easily load this into a Numpy array called `data` with

```
import numpy as np

f = open("filename.txt")
f.readline()  # skip the header
data = np.loadtxt(f)
```

If the stock price is what you want to predict (your `y` value, in scikit-learn terms), then you should split `data` using

```
X = data[:, 1:]  # select columns 1 through end
y = data[:, 0]   # select column 0, the stock price
```

Alternatively, you might be able to massage the [standard Python `csv` module](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) into handling this type of file.

Comment: Is there a way to maintain feature names using this method?

Comment: @AlexFZ: not directly. Instead of just `f.readline()`, you can do `feature_names = f.readline().split()` or some variant of it (the OP's header line isn't nicely space-separated). [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org) has nicer functionality for this.

Comment: Although the questioner provided a space separated file, the question is posed in regards to a csv data file.

Comment: the code you specified generate error ValueError: could not convert string to float:, because my data are string! how to fix that?

Answer (score 71):

A very good alternative to [numpy loadtxt](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) is [read_csv from Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html). The data is loaded into a Pandas dataframe with the big advantage that it can handle mixed data types such as some columns contain text and other columns contain numbers. You can then easily select only the numeric columns and convert to a numpy array with [as_matrix](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html). Pandas will also [read/write excel files and a bunch of other formats](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html).

If we have a csv file named "mydata.csv":

```
point_latitude,point_longitude,line,construction,point_granularity
30.102261, -81.711777, Residential, Masonry, 1
30.063936, -81.707664, Residential, Masonry, 3
30.089579, -81.700455, Residential, Wood   , 1
30.063236, -81.707703, Residential, Wood   , 3
30.060614, -81.702675, Residential, Wood   , 1
```

This will read in the csv and convert the numeric columns into a numpy array for scikit_learn, then modify the order of columns and write it out to an excel spreadsheet:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

input_file = "mydata.csv"


# comma delimited is the default
df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0)

# for space delimited use:
# df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0, delimiter = " ")

# for tab delimited use:
# df = pd.read_csv(input_file, header = 0, delimiter = "\t")

# put the original column names in a python list
original_headers = list(df.columns.values)

# remove the non-numeric columns
df = df._get_numeric_data()

# put the numeric column names in a python list
numeric_headers = list(df.columns.values)

# create a numpy array with the numeric values for input into scikit-learn
numpy_array = df.to_numpy()

# reverse the order of the columns
numeric_headers.reverse()
reverse_df = df[numeric_headers]

# write the reverse_df to an excel spreadsheet
reverse_df.to_excel('path_to_file.xls')
```

Comment: Ok but how to create a scikit learn dataset from that matrix?

Comment: Scikit learn can take pandas dataframes as inputs so it is almost ready. Assuming that "point_granularity" is the target variable you could do y = df['point_granularity'] and X = df[['point_latitude'',point_longitude','line,construction']]

Comment: Since some of the features are categorical you would need to one-hot-encode them for most scikit-learn models: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43038709/1810559

Answer (score 20):

You can look up the loadtxt function in [numpy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html).

To get the optional inputs into the loadtxt method.

A simple change for csv is

```
data =  np.loadtxt(fname = f, delimiter = ',')
```

Answer (score 2):

## Use `numpy` to load csvfile

```
import numpy as np
dataset = np.loadtxt('./example.csv', delimiter=',')
```