# Using prepared data for Sci-kit classification

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use the **Sci-kit learn python library** to classify a bunch of urls for the presence of certain keywords matching a user profile. A user has name, email address ... and a url assigned to them. I have created a txt with the result of each profile data match on each link so it is in the format:

```
Name  Email  Address
  0     1      0      =>Relavent
  1     1      0      =>Relavent
  0     1      1      =>Relavent
  0     0      0      =>Not Relavent
```

Where the 0 or 1 signifies that the attribute was found on the page(each row is a webpage)
How do i give this data to the sci-kit so it can use it to run a classifier? The examples i have seen all have data coming from a predefined sch-kit library such as digits or iris or are being generated in the format i already have. I just dont know how to use the data format i have to provide to the library

***The above is a toy example and i have many more features than 3***

Comment: Just a note - if your data has just 3 features (Name, Email, Address) each 0 or 1 than ANY machine learning is a bad idea. You just have 8 (!) possibilities: 000,100.010.001.110.101.011.111. You can develop perfect (in the sense of your data representation)  rules by hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data needed is a [`numpy` array](http://www.scipy-lectures.org/intro/numpy/array_object.html#what-are-numpy-and-numpy-arrays) (in this case a "matrix") with the shape `(n_samples, n_features)`.

A simple way to read the [csv-file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) to the right format by using [`numpy.genfromtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html). Also refer [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11035992/905596).

Let the contents of a csv file (say `file.csv` in the current working directory) be:

```
a,b,c,target
1,1,1,0
1,0,1,0
1,1,0,1
0,0,1,1
0,1,1,0
```

To load it we do

```
data = np.genfromtxt('file.csv', skip_header=True)
```

The `skip_header` is set to `True`, to prevent reading the header column (The `a,b,c,target` line). Refer [numpy's documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.io.genfromtxt.html) for more details.

Once you load the data, you need to do some pre-processing based on your input data format. The preprocessing could be something like splitting the input and the targets (classification) or splitting the whole dataset into a training and validation set (for cross-validation).

To split the input (feature matrix) from the output (target vector) we do

```
features = data[:, :3]
targets = data[:, 3]   # The last column is identified as the target
```

For the above given CSV data, the arrays will use will look like:

```
features = array([[ 0, 1, 0],
              [ 1, 1, 0],
              [ 0, 1, 1],
              [ 0, 0, 0]])  # shape = ( 4, 3)

targets = array([ 1, 1, 1, 0])  # shape = ( 4, )
```

Now these matrices are passed to the estimator objects `fit` function. If you are using the popular svm classifier then

```
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> linear_svc_model = LinearSVC()
>>> linear_svc_model.fit(X=features, y=targets)
```

Comment: can you add a short example of exactly what this array is supposed to look like?

Comment: Yes that clarifies it up a lot. Out of curiosity, would i use a Bernoulli form of a naive bayes classifier for this example since my features are all binary?

Comment: did the answer satisfy the bounty requirements or should I update it? @JohnBaum